# Finding the Area of a Torus-like surface

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multivariable-calculus, parametric

I'm trying to find out the Area of the following surface:

Let $C$ be the curve associated  to a regular, simple path $\theta:[0,l]\rightarrow  \Bbb  R^2  $; also assume that $((x'(s))^2+((y'(s))^2=b^2$ and let $S$ be the surface generated by the circles of radius $b$, orthogonal to, and centered in points of the curve $\rho(s)=(\theta(s),0) $.

With help from this [source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1045350/let-s-be-the-surface-generated-by-the-circles-of-radius-b-find-a-parametric). I concluded that a convenient parametrization for $S$ is given by:

$$
H(s, t) = ( x(s), y(s), 0) + \sin(t) (0, 0, b) + \cos(t) (b\ y'(s), -b\ x'(s), 0).
$$

I intended to use the fact that the area of $S$ is given by the surface integral:

$$
\int_S ||T_s \times T_t|| \ dv
$$

However,by this approach, the terms of $||T_s \times T_t||$ become really awful. Am I doing something wrong here? What would you recommend?

I found this [approach](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/395284/a-little-help-integrating-this-torus), wich uses the Divergence Theorem. However in this case I´m not sure I can use that since I don´t have a vector field.

Comment: I asked a similar question a *long* time ago (http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/82804/surface-area-of-a-flexible-tube) but never got a full answer. Still interested in the solution!

Comment: Lets hope we get something helpful!

Comment: A gifted student asked me this once (actually his question was about a surface created by revolving one curve about another). My excuse for not calculating it was that the "surface" could be really awful. Say, if $\Theta$ is a circle with diameter $b$. Then $S$ will intersect pretty badly given all the points of $\theta$ will also lie on $S$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I'd be interested in a solution even if it requires assuming that the curvature of $\theta$ is sufficiently large. For instance is it obvious that the answer *isn't* always just $2\pi bl$?